# Are there verbs in -оть not having been subject to the metathesis of the liquids?

Tags: этимология

All Russian verbs ending in *-оть* I can think of had been subject to the metathesis or the liquids and did not have this ending in Proto-Slavic:

> бороть (CS брати) < *барти (cf. *брань*)
>
> колоть (CS клати) < *калти (cf. *заклание*)
>
> молоть (CS млѣти) < *мелти
>
> полоть (CS плѣти) < *пелти
>
> пороть (CS прати) < *порти

Are there verbs that did have this ending in PS or CS?

Comment: I'm afraid you have enumerated all the Russian verbs in -оть, and there were absolutely no verbs in -оти in OS.

Comment: @YellowSky: that's what I thought too, just wanted to confirm (preferably with a source)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [reverse Russian dictionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3a%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-122), there are no Russian verbs ending in *-оть*, other than those listed in the question.

Thus, the answer is no.

That is, all Russian verbs ending in *-оть* have been subject to the metathesis of the liquids, and there are no Russian verbs that inherited that ending (*оть/оти*) from PS.

Comment: What kind of examples are you interested in? There are 78 words ending in -оть in the dictionary (lines 5 to 82), and they are either derivatives of the verbs listed by @Quassnoi (e.g. обмолоть, сполоть, перепороть), or belong to other lexical categories (перхоть, деготь, хоть, вплоть etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, none of the CS or PS verbs could have -оть in its endings, because -оть is a MR ending.

By the way, you have missed the dialect form of надоть.

Comment: надоть isn't verb

Answer (score -1):

How about (по)бороть/перебороть?

Comment: It's a derivative of *бороть* mentioned in the question.